# Length Of A Geodesic Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ with parameterization $X:U\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y>0 \}$ with the metric $(g_{ij})=y^{-2}\delta_{i}^{j}$ and $\alpha(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ where $t\in[0,\pi]$
>
> Find the length $\beta=\alpha\circ X$

How should I approach this?

Comment: First of all, $M$ isn't really in $\Bbb R^3$.  Secondly, $\alpha\circ X$ doesn't make sense. But, in general, how do you find the length of a parametrized curve if you have the first fundamental form $(g_{ij})$?